# teracom router assigning same ip address to different devices

Tags: wireless-networking

I am using a PC and an android device for internet over a single wifi router.
The router is assigning same ip address to both pc and the android device.
only the first device that is connected to network is able to use internet.
Is there anything to do to fix this problem?
(other than static settings)

Comment: Have you tried resetting the router to factory defaults?

Comment: yes.I have changed nothing except the ISP's details.And yes,I have used factory defaults many times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable DHCP option on the router? if you go into your connection properties and then the properties of TCP/IPv4 is there a fixed IP or an automatic?